# intuitive explanation for expected value of the square of a uniform variable

Tags: expected-value, uniform-distribution, intuition

I'm confused about something that should be simple. Suppose I have a random uniform variable $X$ on $[0,1]$. It's fairly clear that the expected value of $X$ is 1/2. By integrating $x^2$ on $[0,1]$, I get that the expected value of $x^2$ is 1/3. I'm struggling to understand this intuitively, as I would expect it to be $1/4$ i.e. $(1/2)^2$.

Comment: That is the difference between $E(X^2)$ and $[E(X)]^2$, or more general, between $E[f(X)]$ and $f[E(X)]$ for non-linear function of $f$.

Comment: $x^2$ is convex, so lookup the *Jensen Inequality*

Comment: Because $V(X) =\frac{1}{12} = E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2 = E(X^2)-\frac 1 4,$ why don't you 'expect' $E(X^2)=\frac 1 3 ?$

Comment: because if I think of it as the area of a square with edge X that is standard uniform, which is completely determined by this X, I don't understand why I can't say the expected area is 1/4.. I understand how to work it out mathematically, but I don't understand intuitively why this random square isn't expected to have area 1/4

Comment: How about this: because squaring decreases smaller numbers more than it decreases larger numbers.

Comment: It is hard to explain this intuitively. Maybe this one has little help. $(1^2 + 2^2 +3^2)/3 = 4.6667$ and  $[(1+2+3)/3]^2 = 4$.

Comment: One way: when you stack your uniform distribution of geometric squares in a third dimension you obtain a *square pyramid.*  If you stack the squares to keep one corner vertically aligned, you can literally *see* that this arises from cutting a cube into three equal-volume parts.